# Why should I specify a more specific MIME type than application/octet-stream when sending an e-mail?

Tags: email, language-agnostic, mime-types

Let's say, for example, that my application sends a mail with a binary attachment (e.g. `somedata.xlsx`). When crafting the mail message (programmatically), I can either

1. just set the MIME type of the attachment to `application/octet-stream` *or*
2. set the "correct" MIME type depending on the actual content of the file (e.g. `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for the aforementioned `somedata.xlsx` file).

Let's also assume that

- I know that actual content of the file (so option 2 is feasible),
- the file is always binary (i.e. human-unreadable) and
- all recipients reside in the "corporate Windows world", where the file extension is the de-facto standard to specify a file's type.

**Why should I go through the hassle of using different MIME types instead of just `application/octet-stream`-ing everyting?** From my experience, all e-mail clients I tested will do "the right thing"¹ when double-clicking an `xlsx` file attached to a mail, regardless whether the MIME type is `application/octet-stream` or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

**Is it just good practice² or does it make a real, practical difference?**

---

¹ i.e., on Windows systems, look up the `xlsx` handler in the registry and start it to open the file.

² Personally, I consider "good practice" to be a very good reason. However, for scientific curiosity, I'm interested if it makes a practical difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is purely speculative.*

Suppose an intermediate system (i.e., some mail filter implemented on the server side) blocks access to/strips away all but 'safe' MIME types to protect the client system.  `application/octet-stream` should probably not be considered safe, but the true MIME type might. In such a scenario, there would be an actual difference in behavior.